# Adding state map using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS.

I'm trying to add a map just of the State of NJ. I figured out to load Google street map, but that's as far as I got.

My goal is to get a Map of NJ with its counties. I found a few maps online that are PDFs. Not sure how to bring it into QGIS and still be able to  geocode with that.

Comment: download the shapefile  and unzip then add (drag and drop) into QGIS > https://njogis-newjersey.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/5f45e1ece6e14ef5866974a7b57d3b95_1

Comment: Thank you, can I change the colors of the counties?

Comment: Check out the "working with vector data" section of the QGIS Manual for information about changing vector layer style/symbology: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/index.html

Comment: I was able to open the attribute table, and select a section of the map, But can't seem to find how to change the color of that one section.

Comment: I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor. For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on the New Jersey Counties Shapefile in QGIS

select Symbology
change from single symbol to categorized...

add/select column GNIS_NAME

click classify.... apply and ok.

[image]

Comment: Thank You!!!  Is it possible to also show the Name of the counties on the map?

Comment: yes, go to labels (see screenshot) and select the field of the label. (you might have adjust the font and size to best fit inside the polygon) transparency can also be done on the file. > https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271205/creating-label-in-qgis